# Highcharts unevenly spaced x-axis with category labels

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to plot some sparse values over a few hundred x-axis category labels. The labels represent points along a geographical entity, so it is necessary to space them according to the actual distance between each point.

I can easily make x-axis categories and plot the values against them, but each category is evenly spaced. If I change to using a complex marker with {x, y, name} properties, the categories are only displayed if they match the tick interval. If a category doesn't match the tick interval, then a number is displayed.

I can produce the following:

[image: highcharts screenshot showing x-axis category labels]

with this small fake sample of data, [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thinkOfaNumber/zLp0h9ys/21/):

```
    ...
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Series 1',
        data: [
          {x:1, y:null, name: 'AB1.1'},
          {x:4, y:1, name: 'AB1.2'},
          {x:5, y:null, name: 'AB1.3'},
          {x:11, y:1, name: 'AB1.4'},
          {x:14, y:null, name: 'AB1.5'},
          {x:14, y:null, name: 'AB1.6'},
          {x:19, y:1, name: 'AB1.7'},
          {x:27, y:1, name: 'AB1.8'},
          {x:28, y:null, name: 'AB1.9'},
          {x:30, y:1, name: 'AB2'},
          {x:37, y:1, name: 'AB2.1'},
          {x:37, y:1, name: 'AB2.2'},
          {x:38, y:1, name: 'AB2.3'},
        ]
    }]
    ...
```

As you can see, the x-axis at this zoom level shows:
0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, AB1.8, AB2, 33, 36, 39

What I *want* is for the x-axis to show *any* of the actual labels (so long as the markers are placed relative to their distance, just like the x-values of the plot); but no generated numbers.

In reality, I have multiple series with around 1,000 points each, but they will all be on the same geographical entity so they all share the same categories. ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thinkOfaNumber/cwsj6y0h/35/) with much more fake data). I can also guarantee that x-values are whole numbers.

I have already tried specifying various x-axis options around ticks, minimum ticks etc. but highcharts still wants to extrapolate evenly spaced labels.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have got the results I want ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thinkOfaNumber/0dpLt9b1/22/)) by setting `xAxis.tickPositions` dynamically on zoom. To begin with, I pick about 35 x-Axis positions to display my markers (an arbitrary number but I picked something that worked for my fixed-width chart size).

Then, on zoom, I update the chart to display about 30 markers that are within the new zoom level.

This way I always have a good number of markers displayed, and they are unevenly spaced because that's what my actual data is like.

Zoomed out (L) and zoomed in (R):

[image: Zoomed out] [image: Zoomed in]

this is an array of all x-axis points that have a marker-a few thousand

```
allTicks = [1, 6, 9, 9, ...]
```

a function to select 30 points from the given array

```
function selectTickPositions(tickPositions) {
    const maxTicks = 30;
    if (tickPositions.length <= maxTicks) return tickPositions; // return all
    let mod = Math.round(tickPositions.length / maxTicks);
    // always select the first and the last, and then up to 30 more
    return tickPositions.filter((val, idx) => idx == 0 || idx == tickPositions.length - 1 || idx % mod == 0);
}
```

setup the chart options:

```
let theChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        ...
        events: {
          // the selection event is fired when a zoom selection is made
            selection: (event) => {
                let ticks;
                if (event.xAxis) {
                    let min = event.xAxis[0].min;
                    let max = event.xAxis[0].max;
                    ticks = selectTickPositions(allTicks.filter(t => t >= min && t <= max));
                } else {
                    ticks = selectTickPositions(allTicks);
                }
                theChart.update({
                    xAxis: {
                        tickPositions: ticks
                    }
                });
                return true;
            }
        }
    },
    ...
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        tickPositions: selectTickPositions(allTicks)
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your requirement very well, but here is my attempt of showing just a `xAxis.labels` if the label is a category string.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4xdjw5L7/

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'category',
  endOnTick: true,
  startOnTick: true,
        labels: {
            formatter() {
                if (typeof this.value !== 'number') {
                    return this.value
                }
            }
        }
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

Let me know if this is an expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that helps get rid of the numbers, but is there any way to display some more labels? e.g. on the jsfiddle, only two labels are shown. I tried setting 
`xAxis{ tickInterval: 1,  minTickInterval: 1, labels: { step: 1, ...} }` but I have to zoom in a number of times before I see any more labels.